# Does not work perfectly for Online User in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am making a classified website in wordpress with classipress theme,

> http://www.mohibsalahuddin.com/client/ads/test-ad/

for showing author is online or offline on ad page, i wrote the following code, but it does not work if two users registered at a time... If registered user wants to see another registered user's status it always shows offline...
**I though may be i missed session start thing do i have to write it? Kindly help me in this**

I write the code below

```
First I create the table in MYSQL
CREATE TABLE wordpress_users_online` (
user_id int(11) default NULL,
full_name varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
session_id varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
ip_address varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
time_entry varchar(14) NOT NULL default '',
time_last_click varchar(14) NOT NULL default '',
last_page_url varchar(255) NOT NULL default ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM;`
```

THEN I WRITE THE FILE wordpress_users_online.php with following code

```
<?php
define('TABLE_USERS', 'wordpress_users');
define('TABLE_USER_ONLINE', 'wordpress_users_online');

  function update_user_online() {
    //global $user_id;

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if ($current_user->ID && $current_user->user_login) {

      $wo_user_id = $current_user->ID;
      $wo_full_name = $user['user_nicename'];

    } else {
      $wo_user_id = '';
      $wo_full_name = 'Guest';
    }

    $wo_session_id = session_id();
    $wo_ip_address = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    $wo_last_page_url = getenv('REQUEST_URI');

    $current_time = time();
    $xx_mins_ago = ($current_time - 300); 

// remove entries that have expired
    mysql_query("delete from " . TABLE_USER_ONLINE . " where time_last_click < '" . $xx_mins_ago . "'");

    $stored_user_query = mysql_query("select count(*) as count from " . TABLE_USER_ONLINE . " where session_id = '" . mysql_escape_string($wo_session_id) . "'");
    $stored_user = mysql_fetch_array($stored_user_query);

    if ($stored_user['count'] > 0) {
      mysql_query("update " . TABLE_USER_ONLINE . " set user_id = '" . (int)$wo_user_id . "', full_name = '" . mysql_escape_string($wo_full_name) . "', ip_address = '" . mysql_escape_string($wo_ip_address) . "', time_last_click = '" . mysql_escape_string($current_time) . "', last_page_url = '" . mysql_escape_string($wo_last_page_url) . "' where session_id = '" . mysql_escape_string($wo_session_id) . "'");
    } else {
      mysql_query("insert into " . TABLE_USER_ONLINE . " (user_id, full_name, session_id, ip_address, time_entry, time_last_click, last_page_url) values ('" . (int)$wo_user_id . "', '" . mysql_escape_string($wo_full_name) . "', '" . mysql_escape_string($wo_session_id) . "', '" . mysql_escape_string($wo_ip_address) . "', '" . mysql_escape_string($current_time) . "', '" . mysql_escape_string($current_time) . "', '" . mysql_escape_string($wo_last_page_url) . "')");
    }
  }


  function is_online($user_id) {  

    $stored_user_query = mysql_query("select user_id from  ".TABLE_USER_ONLINE."  where user_id = '" . mysql_escape_string($user_id) . "'");
    $stored_user = mysql_fetch_array($stored_user_query);

    if(isset($stored_user['user_id'])){
      $online = '<img src="http://www.mohibsalahuddin.com/client/wp-content/themes/classipress-313/images/online.png" border="0" />&nbsp;Online'; 
      echo $online;
      }

    else {
      $online = '<img src="http://www.mohibsalahuddin.com/client/wp-content/themes/classipress-313/images/offline.png" border="0" />&nbsp;Offline';
      echo $online;

          }           

    return $online; 

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a wordpress plugin for this already...
--Edit--
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-useronline/

---

Sorry the following was the original suggestions but they were the wrong links:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/who-is-online/faq/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wassup/

Remember, don't re-invent the wheel unless you're going to make it hover too.

Comment: i think  in my case it doesnot work,
open this url

in the below you find a chat tab, here you find a online status, i want to check that is the user is online or not so the visitor can do chat with him
http://www.mohibsalahuddin.com/client/ads/test-ad/

Comment: Undress those plug-ins I listed. You're right, they may not be perfect, but they'll give you a different perspective.

Comment: Actually... I'm adding a better one. I totally did a quick search and gave you the wrong first plug-in link.

Comment: see my above code its shows only one user at a time online if two user comes it make it offline, so how can overcome on this